# Semifinite measure Qualifying Exam question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Recall that a measure $\mu$ is semifinite if for any $E \in \mathbb{M}$ with $\mu(E)=\infty$, there exists $F \in \mathbb{M}$ with $F \subset E$ and $0 < \mu(F) < \infty$. Show that if $\mu$ is semifinite, then for any $E \in \mathbb{M}$, $\mu(E) = \sup\left\lbrace \mu(F) : F\in \mathbb{M}, F \subset E, \mu(F) < \infty \right\rbrace$

So I know that $\mu(E) \geq \sup\left\lbrace \mu(F) : F\in \mathbb{M}, F \subset E, \mu(F) < \infty \right\rbrace$ for all $F \subset E$, so I just need to show the reverse inequality, which I'm stuck at.

If $\mu(E) = \infty$, then we showed in a long ago homework problem (and presumably would have to reprove on the qualifying exam), that for any $C>0$, there exists $F \subset E$ such that $C < \mu(F) < \infty$, so that would show the equality since the supremum over all such $F$ would have to be $\infty$.

If $\mu(E) < \infty$, I don't see how to show that $\mu(E) \leq \sup\left\lbrace \mu(F) : F\in \mathbb{M}, F \subset E, \mu(F) < \infty \right\rbrace$

Comment: If $\mu(E)<\infty$, then $E$ is one of the sets over which the supremum is taken, right?

Comment: @carmichael561 I wasn't sure since I was a little confused over whether we could say $E \subset E$ (I read $\subset$ as strict containment)

Comment: I think it's just supposed to be containment. Imagine that $X=\{0,1\}$ with $\mu(\{0\})=\mu(\{1\})=1$. Then $\mu$ is finite (so certainly semifinite), but $\mu(X)$ is strictly greater than the maximum of $\mu(F)$ for proper subsets of $X$.

Comment: @carmichael561 Ok fair point. I'll make a mental note to remember that it means containment

Comment: It's too late here to write a real proof.  Tired sketch:  If $\mu(E) = \infty$, there is an $F_1 \subset E$ with $\mu(F_1) < \infty$.  But then, $\mu(E \setminus F_1) = \infty$ and we get $F_2$ ... Then $\mu(\cup_j F_j) < \infty$ is an unbounded increasing sequence because ...